# Retrieve MySQL data using JSON, PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm having a trouble getting data from my database;
Here's my code

```
<?php
 require('connectionT.php');

 $result= mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM restaurants");
 while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
  {
        $tmp[]=$row;

  }

  echo json_encode ($tmp);

?>
```

When I execute my code, I just get a blank page.
Anyone?

Comment: Does the database contain values? Is the database connection right? Did you enable error reporting? http://stackoverflow.com/a/845025/1864587

Comment: Use error_reporting(E_ALL); and check paste error here.

Comment: Show use the contents of `connectionT.php`

Comment: I'm using a small database, it has like 23 rows. When I try to use a query like " SELECT subCategory From restaurants". Works perfectly. 

This is my ConnectionT.php

http://paste.ofcode.org/ECXUkazqtGtDy8qaQM6bqy

Comment: No error. Just a blank page.